# Which .dll contains HTMLElement Class?

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel

I am using VBA from Excel (Office 2010) to navigate through a webpage in Internet Explorer.  My problem is I cannot declare an instance of an `HtmlElement` e.g.

```
Dim myHtmlEl As HtmlElement
```

Returns the error "User defined type not defined."

I have seen this problem before when I wanted to declare and instance of an `InternetExplorer` object.  The solution to that was to create reference by **Tools >> References... >> Microsoft Internet Controls** in the VBA editor. My understanding is that *Microsoft Internet Controls* is a `.dll` with a definition of the `InternetExplorer` class.

Therefore to create an instance of an `HtmlElement` object I need to reference the `.dll` that defines that class. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests that the `.dll` is *System Windows Forms*. I linked that but the class is still undefined.

How do I know which .dll contains `HtmlElement` class?

Comment: Add a reference to "MicroSoft HTML Object Library"

Comment: If for some reason Tim's reference does not work for early-binding, you could try late-binding `Dim myHtmlEl As Object`.

Comment: Works.  But how do you look up which reference I need to connect?

Comment: There's no short-cut to finding which reference you need to add, but if you google "VBA HTMLelement" you will likely find the answer in the first half-dozen hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [late binding solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/491e2682-ad3a-4622-bb80-c0979a905439/how-to-loop-through-the-elements-of-a-website) may suit your needs.

```
Dim myHtmlElement As Variant 
Dim IE As Variant 

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
IE.Visible = True 

IE.Navigate "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" 

' Wait while site is loading
While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

' Get An Element
Set myHtmlElement = IE.Document.getElementById("myInput") 

' Set the value of an element
If Not myHtmlElement Is Nothing Then myHtmlElement.Value = ActiveCell.Value

' Click a button
Set myHtmlElement = IE.Document.getElementById("searchButton") 
myHtmlElement.Click

' Wait while site is loading
While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

' Navigate the IE object 
Dim i As Integer 
For i = 0 To IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a").Length - 1 
    If IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div").Item(i).innerText Like "ab*" Then 
        ' Do Something
    End If
Next
```

Above code is based upon the linked MSDN forum.